# Swift 4.2 dictionary could not find value by key

Tags: swift

I generate keys to choose values for dictionary by some function.
When I compare hash values of generated keys and keys from dictionary they are identical. But if I try to get something from dictionary by generated keys — I got nil.

```
let vCoords = verticesFrom(axes: result)
print ("Generated:")
vCoords.forEach { 
    print($0, $0.hashValue)
}
print ("Stored:")
grid.forEach {
    print($0.key, $0.key.hashValue, $0.value.data)
}

let data1 = vCoords.map { grid[$0]?.data }.compactMap{$0}

print ("\nData: \(data1)")
```

Listing is:

```
Generated:
["x": -100.0, "y": -100.0] 8549935799981594856
["x": -100.0, "y": -50.0] -5857979117386601619
["x": -10.0, "y": -100.0] 5216433118710295311
["x": -10.0, "y": -50.0] 3277190687522282455
Stored:
["x": -100.0, "y": -100.0] 8549935799981594856 [NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace 1 1 1 1]
["x": -100.0, "y": -50.0] -5857979117386601619 [NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace 0.583333 0.583333 0.583333 0.666667]
["x": -10.0, "y": -100.0] 5216433118710295311 [NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace 0.685 0.685 0.685 1]
["x": -10.0, "y": -50.0] 3277190687522282455 [NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace 0 0 1 1]

Data: []
```

Of course I can iterate by vCoords by grid and compare each value, but in this case I don't need Dictionary and algorithm is slower. What could be wrong?

Comment: A *self-contained* example demonstrating the problem is always helpful.

Comment: did you find the solution ?

Comment: Yea, Keys has to be not only Hashable, but Equitable too. (if I remember well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are returning an array of dictionaries here:

```
let vCoords = verticesFrom(axes: result)
```

Specifically something like (but not a dictionary since it is already conforming to a Equatable)

```
[[String: Int]]    
[["x": -100.0, "y": -100.0], ["x": -100.0, "y": -50.0].... ]
```

Here is what you need to change so you get the expected result:

In case you haven't already created a custom object for your

`verticesFrom(axes: result)`,

you should create a custom class and make it conform to the `Equatable` protocol:

```
class CustomCoordinate: Equatable {    
    var customX: Int
    var customY: Int

// ...
   public static func == (lhs: CustomCoordinate, rhs: CustomCoordinate) -> Bool {
        return lhs.customX == rhs.customX && lhs.customY == rhs.customY
    }
}
```

**Otherwise**, if this implies too many changes in your project and you need a quick fix:

```
let data1 = vCoords.map ({ vectCoord -> [String: Int]? in // [String: Int]? or whatever objet you are using
    grid.first(where: { (customCoord) -> Bool in
        return customCoord["x"] == vectCoord["x"] && customCoord["y"] == vectCoord["y"]
    })
}).compactMap{$0}
```

Comment: It’s not exactly a Dictionary, but yes. I made them equitable and it works now. I was sure Dictionary uses hashValue of key to get value. But not.

Comment: @Łukasz `Dictionary` uses `hash` but it also uses equality if the hash values are the same. That's why `Hashable` extends `Equatable`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Dictionary uses '==' to compare keys, not just hash value. I changed func '==' for key struct and now is ok.

Comment: Of course it does. Equal values must have the same hash value, but not vice versa.

Comment: Hash values are only used to sort values into buckets of [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) (`Dictionary` is one), to make retrieve from it logarithmic instead of linear. But then to find exact element in the bucket it uses equality.

Comment: @user28434 Actually, value list is retrieved from a bucket in constant time O(1), not logarithmic time.